# delegate method not working on SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, slide

i want to refresh my main view on slide menu did select method with categorically

i have used SWRevealViewController to load my slide menu and its working fine but i cant understand how to assign delegate to the slide menu controller and use it?

here is [the link](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for awesome library by john lusch

slide menu controller.h

```
@protocol SlideViewControllerDelegate
@required
-(void)menuViewControllerDidFinishWithCategoryId:(NSInteger)categoryId;
@end

 @interface SlideViewController : 

UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    __weak id<SlideViewControllerDelegate> slideDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SlideViewControllerDelegate> slideDelegate;
@end
```

slide menu controller.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.slideDelegate menuViewControllerDidFinishWithCategoryId:indexPath.row];
}
```

viewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,SlideViewControllerDelegate>
```

viewController.m

in my view did load method

```
SlideViewController *slideView = [[SlideViewController alloc]init];
slideView.slideDelegate = self;

- (void)menuViewControllerDidFinishWithCategoryId:(NSInteger)categoryId
{
    self.categId = [catIdArray objectAtIndex:categoryId];
    NSLog(@"cat id %@",categId);
    [self getQuestions];
    [self.feedTableView reloadData];
}
```

//Log above is never executed
so i think may be i am wrong with assigning delegate to the swreveal view controller slide menu

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in the slide menu controller (before calling the delegate)? Is it the delegate valid with the correct instance?

Comment: i dont understand your concern ???

Comment: In your controller you have the method "- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath". There you call "[self.slideDelegate menuViewControllerDidFinishWithCategoryId:indexPath.row];". Before calling this method, put a breakpoint so you can check the value of the delegate to understand if it is nil or not

Comment: yes you are right the delegate is nil before that call. what should i do now?

Comment: any progress on that?

Comment: @PonyLand yup please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it to set a delegate to a reveal controller do like this

`[(SlideViewController *)self.revealViewController.rearViewController setSlideDelegate:self];`

Comment: I did this in my viewdidload method after you set your slideDelegate.

Comment: sorry to say i didnt get you... view did load of slideMenu view controller or viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should init `SlideViewController` by

```
- (id)initWithRearViewController:(UIViewController *)rearViewController frontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController;
```

which says in the `README.md`.

Comment: i want to refresh my main view on slide menu did select method with category id. just see my code to know what i m trying here

Answer (score 0):

Remove that lines:

```
{
    __weak id<SlideViewControllerDelegate> slideDelegate;
}
```

Your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SlideViewControllerDelegate> slideDelegate;
```

it's enought.